# How to store Database Values in Hash Map

Tags: perl, hashmap, dbi

I am working on my Office project and stuck from last two days, I have the Database which I can fetch table wise, I have to store each table information in some hash map so that I can use it and get the needed detail later on(DB contains few values which I need for later use to compare with my other values which are coming from some XL sheet).

Below is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBI;
use strict;

use warnings;
use Switch;
use Data::Dumper;
use Spreadsheet::Read qw(ReadData);

my @dbValues=("");
my @dbValuesInfo;
my $i;
my %testCb;

if($dbType eq "mysql"){
#$database = "trustid";
$dsn = "DBI:$dbType:database=$database;host=$host:port=3306,DBSOCK = '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'";
$userid = "XXXX";
$password = 'XXXX';
}else{
$dbType="postgres";
$userid = "postgres";
$password = "postgres";
$dsn = "DBI:$dbType:database=$database;host=$host:port=XXXX";
}

my $dbcon = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password) or die "Can't connect to database: $DBI::errstr\n";
print "connected to the database\n";

my $notables = $dbcon->tables();
print "No of tables : $notables"."\n" ;
my @tables = $dbcon->tables(undef, undef, undef, 'TABLE');

my $len = @tables;
for (my $i = 0; $i < $len; $i = $i + 1)
    {
print ("\@tables[$i] = $tables[$i]\n");
print("\n");        
} 
my $sth = $dbcon->prepare('select * from active_table_set');

$sth->execute();
 
while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
   $database=join(',', @row);
   print($database."\n");
   if($dbType eq "mysql"){
#$database = "trustid";
$dsn = "DBI:$dbType:database=$database;host=$host:port=3306,DBSOCK = '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'";
$userid = "XXXX";
$password = 'XXXX';
}else{
$dbType="postgres";
$userid = "postgres";
$password = "postgres";
$dsn = "DBI:$dbType:database=$database;host=$host:port=XXXX";
}
$dbcon = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password) or die "Can't connect to database: $DBI::errstr\n";
print "connected to the database\n";
@tables = $dbcon->tables(undef, undef, undef, 'TABLE');
$len = @tables;
for (my $i = 0; $i < $len; $i = $i + 1)
    {
print ("\@tables[$i] = $tables[$i]\n");
print("\n");
if($tables[$i] eq '`trustid_b`.`carriers`'){
$sth = $dbcon->prepare('select * from carriers');

$sth->execute();
while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
@dbValues= join(',', @row). "\n";
#print(@row)."\n"
@dbValuesInfo=(\@dbValues);
}
}

} 
}
for( $i = 0; $i <= $#dbValuesInfo; $i++){    
$testCb{$i+1} =  $dbValuesInfo[$i];    
}
```

I tried to create one Hash map in loop but every time in the loop it get updated, so I am not getting how to store every individual row of database as single array kind of thing in my hash map where the key should be id.

below is the kind of the code snippet I have used for storing it in hash map, & it is code which I have copied from my code above.

```
    my @dbValues=("");
    my @dbValuesInfo;
    my $i;
    my %testCb;
    
    
    @dbValuesInfo=(\@dbValues);
    
    for( $i = 0; $i <= $#dbValuesInfo; $i++){
    # push the test data  on the array
    $testCb{$i+1} =  $dbValuesInfo[$i];
    }
```

The output of the code is :

connected to the database
No of tables : 1
@tables[0] = `control`.`active_table_set`

trustid_b
connected to the database
@tables[0] = `trustid_b`.`ani_pre_translation`

@tables[1] = `trustid_b`.`ani_pre_translation_test`

@tables[2] = `trustid_b`.`carriers`

Use of uninitialized value $row[5] in join or string at ./aa.pl line 93.
Use of uninitialized value $row[5] in join or string at ./aa.pl line 93.

Also, That would be great if I can Store 'Null' on the empty columns of the database in my Hash map.

Comment: Database contains:  Use of uninitialized value $row[5] in join or string at ./aa.pl line 89.

95,25,https://devapi-primary.trustidinc.com/tid,wingsfinancialnuancedevtestsbc,wingsfinancialnuancedevtest,,UNKNOWN,0,2022-03-03 07:30:37,2022-03-03 07:30:37,Wings Financial_Dev,Y,Y,Y,ivr.localdomain,U,damien

Use of uninitialized value $row[5] in join or string at ./aa.pl line 89.

96,25,https://devapi-primary.trustidinc.com/tid,wingsfinancialnuancedevtestsbc,wingsfinancialnuancedevtest,,UNKNOWN,2,2022-03-03 07:31:03,2022-03-03 07:31:03,Wings Financial_Dev,Y,Y,Y,ivr.localdomain,U,damien

Comment: FYI, don't share sensitive info like userid, passwords here. You can make it something like 'xxxxx' or 'zzzzz'.

Comment: You are only using arrays and array references. There are no hashes. It's not entirely clear to me what you are trying to do. // I don't understand why you fetch all possible tables from the DB, then iterate that, and only act on one specific one. Is that because you don't know if that table will exist, and you want to add different fetching code for each table? // It looks like you are reconnecting to the database inside of the loop. You're overwriting the existing connection doing that.

Comment: @simbabque yes exactly, i dont know the name of database even, I have to fetch every info, I have to access each table name through my code only . actally why i am re writing is bcz my db is secured and it is something related to my work so i think db is present inside db kind of thing. No, connection is happen only once. One table code is only written i have to do it for all, fetched the name of table to come to know the names od tables for alter use.

Comment: @ShobhitSolanki: Please [edit your code](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72456935/edit) and fix the indentation.